# Disable Pentaho Logging

Tags: logging, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Pentaho and had a question regarding the PDI Logs. All the running and error logs are appended in the file pdi.log in Kettle/Data Integration/logs. The file keeps increasing in size which is creating memory issues. 
I want to find a way to stop this logging. I have removed logging from Setting->Logs of a job, but the logs are still getting created and appended to pdi.log
I am working on version 8.3
Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 2):

The logging defined in Log4J configuration file. By default log data append in log file available in installation folder.

To stop logging into file you have to comment out file appender's defined in loggers as below

Existing: this log4j.xml configuration file available in classes folder

This line need to be commented in both jobs and transformation logger definition

appender-ref ref="pdi-execution-appender"

Rather than disabling logging recommendation is you can redirect logging into another location where you have enough memory for future tracking. to change log file path please change path defined in corresponding appender definition.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the logging settings are configured in the `/data-integration/system/osgi/log4j.xml` file. Not sure how you'd necessarily STOP all logging or why you'd want to do that, but you can start there.

Answer (score 0):

By default `ConsoleLoggingEventListener.java` writes to `System.out`

Documentation: [ConsoleLoggingEventListener](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/core/logging/ConsoleLoggingEventListener.java)

To disable `ConsoleLoggingEventListener`:

```java
System.setProperty("KETTLE_DISABLE_CONSOLE_LOGGING", "Y"); 
// probably an equivalent in kettle.properties
```